# What is the purpose of "? extends A"?

Tags: java, generics

If I have a list like this:

```
static ArrayList<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

What is the point of `? extends A`? Does it mean that I am making a list of only subclasses that MUST inherit from A?

Normally I do it like this:

```
static ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Comment: [Best answer ever](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: @MarounMaroun link only answer :P ?? :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun That is a link to generics. Don't just throw links at me man.

Comment: @J_Strauton a direct link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).

Comment: @J_Strauton Read the tutorial and you'll understand what it's about.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Link only *comment* ;)

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279331/main-intention-or-purpose-of-wildcard-notation-extends-t?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894335/generic-lower-unbound-vs-upper-bounded-wildcards?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541849/wildcards-in-generics-super-t-works-while-extends-t-does-not?rq=1

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful information!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vQf4qyMXg#t=1323 -- best resource to start learning about co/contra-variance in Java. A talk from Joshua Bloch about some chapters on his Effective Java. Flex your PECS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extends` keyword means that the class on the left of this keyword would be using all the methods and properties from the class that is one the right side. `?` wouldn't be there. Some name would be. A name of a class.

```
static ArrayList<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

In the above code, you're making a new `ArrayList` object which uses (implements/extends) the Class `A` for its methods and properties but is not in real `A`.

```
static ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Whereas in the second code that you usually use, you're actually creating an Object which uses class `A` in real.

In Java we call it **inheritance** where one class inherits all the properties and functions of the other class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Let me double check. Does that mean that I am casting any future class that goes in that list as a child class of A?

Comment: No not child, but some sort of a clone of it. Because it would have all the methods of Class `A` in it.

Comment: Considering that `class B extends A {}; List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>(); list.add(new B())` compiles fine, how do the first and second declarations differ?

Comment: @user2864740: They differ in that, by contrast with your version, `List<? extends A> list = ...; list.add(new B())` does *not* compile fine (because the compiler can't tell *which* subtype of `A` is the list's component-type).

Comment: @ruakh Then I'm left confused about "In the above code, you're making a new ArrayList object which uses (implements/extends) the Class A for its methods and properties but is not in real A" and "Whereas in the second code that you usually use, you're actually creating an Object which uses class A in real".

Comment: @user2864740: The reason you're confused is that this answer is total gibberish. I can't believe that six people upvoted it. (Personally, I'm one of the two downvoters.)

Answer (score 2):

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html):

> The upper bounded wildcard, `<? extends Foo>`, where `Foo` is any type, matches `Foo` and any subtype of `Foo`.

So, answering the question *"Does it mean that I am making a list of only subclasses that MUST inherit from A?"*

It means that you are making a list of objects which types **are `A` or inherit from `A`**.

**Edit:**

One difference is that in the second code

```
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

you will be able to refer to the type `A` anywhere in the code.

Comment: So how does this differ from the second code without type-bounds? When is one appropriate over the other?

Comment: @user2864740 bring up an excellent point!